# wget to download files from list of urls and naming it from other list of names

Tags: command-line, bash, downloads, wget

I Have two text files - one of them contains urls of images that I want to download and other text file has the list of names corresponding to the urls of first files.

Example content of text file 1:

```
www.img.com/1/
www.img.com/2/
www.img.com/3/
```

Example Content of text file 2:

```
ab.jpg
bc.jpg
cd.jpg
```

I know how to use `wget` command for a list of urls :

```
wget -i exampletextfile1.txt
```

Is there any way or syntax to download files from first text file using `wget` and name them with respect to corresponding names from other text file?

Comment: I'd say you need to write a script that  [reads both files into arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494945) an then iterates over them calling `wget` in each loop.

Comment: As you write it, contents of text file 1 are *not* URL's to images. They are URL's  to directories on the internet, so will display an "index.html" file if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge files into one using the `paste` tool:

```
paste -d "" file1.txt file2.txt > result.txt
```

The result of merging your examples:

```
www.img.com/1/ab.jpg
www.img.com/2/bc.jpg
www.img.com/3/cd.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# URLs.txt
# NAMEs.txt

count=1
while read URL; do
  NAME=$(sed "${count}q;d" NAMEs.txt)
  wget -O $NAME $URL
  count=$((count+1))
done <URLs.txt
```